# Can I express the rate of a reaction as percent per second (%/s)?

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics, concentration, units

Rate is calculated as change in concentration over change in time, so usually $\pu{M/s}$ $(\pu{mol L-1 s-1}).$

Say, I'm calculating it for $20\%$ solution of ammonium hydroxide, so my final rate is in $\pu{\%/s}.$ Is this a proper format, or should I calculate for $\pu{mol L-1}?$

Answer (score 6):

According to *IUPAC Recommendations* for chemical kinetics [[1](https://doi.org/10.1351/pac199668010149)], rates $\nu$ are defined for reactant $\ce{B}$ and product $\ce{Y}$ as a time $(t)$ derivative of the amount $n$ (in general) or per unit volume $V$ (for the closed system):

$$
\begin{array}{lll}
\hline
\text{System} & \text{Consumption} & \text{Formation} \\
\hline
\text{Open} & \displaystyle\nu(n_\ce{B}) = -\frac{\mathrm dn_\ce{B}}{\mathrm dt} & \displaystyle\nu(n_\ce{Y}) = \frac{\mathrm dn_\ce{Y}}{\mathrm dt} \\
\hline
\text{Closed} & \displaystyle\nu(c_\ce{B}) = -\frac{1}{V}\frac{\mathrm dn_\ce{B}}{\mathrm dt} & \displaystyle\nu(c_\ce{Y}) = \frac{1}{V}\frac{\mathrm dn_\ce{Y}}{\mathrm dt} \\
  & \displaystyle\nu(c_\ce{B})|_{V = \mathrm{const}} = -\frac{\mathrm d[\ce{B}]}{\mathrm dt} & \displaystyle\nu(c_\ce{Y})|_{V = \mathrm{const}} = \frac{\mathrm d[\ce{Y}]}{\mathrm dt} \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

Rates of consumption and formation that are measured in $\pu{mol L-1 s-1}$ are defined for the closed system at constant volume, and molar concentration arises from its definition.
Whether you can or cannot substitute molar concentration $c_i$ with fractions can be answered by looking at the relationship between the two.

For example, molar concentration $c_i$ expressed in terms of [mass fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_fraction_(chemistry)#Molar_concentration) $\omega_i$ via the density of solution $\rho$ and the molar mass $M_i$ of the $i$th component:

$$c_i = \frac{\omega_i \rho}{M_i}\tag{1}$$

Similarly, molar concentration $c_i$ expressed in terms of [mole fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mole_fraction#Molar_concentration) $x_i$ via the density of solution $\rho$ and the average molar mass $\bar{M}$ of the solution:

$$c_i = \frac{x_i\rho}{\bar{M}}\tag{2}$$

As you can see, there is a problem: as the reaction progresses, not only the amounts (or fractions) would change, but also the density and the molar mass of the solution *may and will change in most cases*, which leads to *inapplicability of percent fractions as time derivatives*.
All in all, in chemistry it's *just easier* to manipulate with the quantities based on amount of substance.

#### References

1. Laidler, K. J. A Glossary of Terms Used in Chemical Kinetics, Including Reaction Dynamics (IUPAC Recommendations 1996). *Pure and Applied Chemistry* **2009**, 68 (1), 149–192. DOI: [10.1351/pac199668010149](https://doi.org/10.1351/pac199668010149). (Free Access)

Comment: I don't fully understand. I get that % values change over the reaction (first order btw) , but if I have a rate that's in %/s, isn't that expressing the change in concentration in and of itself?

Answer (score 2):

To summarize, and to answer the question, it is correct to say that the rate of a chemical reaction can be expressed in % per second if and only if the reaction is first order. This percentage is the first order rate constant $k$.

Comment: Can I get a source? That % is first order?

Answer (score 0):

For a reaction like this: $\ce{aA +bB⟶cC +dD}$, the rate is given by

Rate=$−a\frac{d[A]}{dt}=−b\frac{d[B]}{dt}=c\frac{d[C]}{dt}=d\frac{d[D]}{dt}$ where the unit is usually $\ce{mol L^{-1}{s^{-1}}}$.

The rate of a reaction is different for different orders and has different units of the same. It's unit usually has the terms $\ce{mol, L, and s}$.

- For a zero order reaction,

Rate= k, unit= $\ce{mol L^{-1}{s^{-1}}}$

- For a first order reaction,

Rate= $\ce{k[A]}$, unit=$\ce{s^{-1}}$

- For a second order reaction,

Rate=$\ce{k[A]^2}$, unit=$\ce{L mol^{-1}{s^{-1}}}$